# How do I use a feature on a website using python

Tags: python, google-chrome, click

I am trying to figure out how to activate/click on a feature using python. Like it goes to a page and click on a certain button. How can I do this? Are there any modules that may help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the selenium package in Python.

Once you `pip install selenium` and download chromedriver, you should be able to use something like this -

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "your_url"
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/path/to/chromedriver", chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.delete_all_cookies()
driver.get(url)
```

And after your page opens, you'll first have to find the element using inspect and then based on its name/id/class/etc, you can click on it using -
`driver.find_element_by_name('<element_name>').click()`